# How to create a UITextField like MFMailComposer has?

Tags: ios4, uitextfield, mfmailcomposer

I want to create a MFMailComposer like UITextField like when we type an email address it converted into blue round button like shape. I do not want to use Three20's MailComposer. I want to create my own.Any idea how to achieve this? or if there is already a UITextField or whatever control is out there please let me know.

EDIT: I've checked three20's TTCatalog demo. And It has all the things I want except a few like when I type an email address manually it's not converted into the blue button.Also I want to send mail using my own methods because I'm doing encryption of message. And I want to get all the email addresses entered in the To field and I want a Cc/Bcc field like MFMailComposer has.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [TITokenFieldView](https://github.com/thermogl/TITokenField) - you may be able to use/adapt for your needs

Comment: @ wuf810 thanks dude it's awesome. I wish there is the functionality to add contact from address book to when we tap on + button. If you could can you please modify the source to add email from contact list when we tap on + button and also how do we get all the emails back cause I want to send email to all the address entered in the to field

Comment: It's openSource so you can modify it yourself. nb there is a delegate method when the + button is clicked. Really it is pretty straight forward so have ago. You'll be pleased when it's done